# Remove stopwords and tolower function slow on a Corpus in R

Tags: r, performance, text-mining, tm

I  have corpus roughly with 75 MB data. I am trying to use the following command

```
tm_map(doc.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
tm_map(doc.corpus, tolower)
```

This two alone functions are taking at least 40 mins to run. I am looking for speeding up the process as I am using `tdm` matrix for my model.

I have tried commands like `gc()` and `memory.limit(10000000)` very frequently but I am not able to speed up my process speed.

I have a system with `4GB` RAM and running a local database to read the input data.

Hoping for suggestions to speed up!

Comment: Parallelize your computation? Split your text into chunks of say 20 MB and run on different cores.I believe you would be fine because removing stopwords is just a dictionary task and context-free. Also, R is very slow for these things, so if speed is crucial to you consider rewriting it in something faster, like C.

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze Can I parallelize it in R? I am comfortable working with R an looking at reducing the time lag!

Comment: So I usually either 1) use the `parallel` package, which is pretty nice and has its own analogs to `apply` and such, or 2) recode some parts of the code in inline C or C++ via the `compiler` and `inline` packages. I think you should take a look at the `parallel` package to begin.

Comment: `quanteda` is another text processing package that claims to be [built for efficiency and speed](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quanteda/vignettes/quickstart.html).

Comment: To expand a little, I would advise to divide your corpus into *n-1* chunks, where *n-1* is how many cores you have. Then, write a function similar to `parallel=function(corpusPart)tm_map(corpusPart, removeWords, stopwords("english"))`. Now, you can feed `parallel()` to the `parLapply()` method.

Comment: @bouncyball I used that and the speed in there is good! but it gives a `sparsematrix` I am not sure if that is just as same as the `tdm` in tm package

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze Mind reproducing with some sample data in the answers section? That would probably save a lot of time for me !

Comment: @ShivaPrakash Sorry I can't do it right now but I will maybe post one later when I have time. Essentially you will split the task in steps: `lapply(c("parallel","tm"), require, character.only = TRUE)
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)` : sets up the parallelization. Export the `tm` library : `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(tm))` Now, assuming you have a list of Corpus stored in `corpusList`, you can do something like `parLapply(cl, corpusList,
          function(corpusPart)
            tm_map(corpusPart, removeWords, stopwords("english")))`

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze Will give it a shot sometime and may be will keep you posted! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can give quanteda a try

```
library(stringi)
library(tm)
library(quanteda)

txt <- stri_rand_lipsum(100000L)
print(object.size(txt), units = "Mb")
# 63.4 Mb

system.time(
  dfm <- dfm(txt, toLower = TRUE, ignoredFeatures = stopwords("en")) 
)
# Elapsed time: 12.3 seconds.
#        User      System verstrichen 
#       11.61        0.36       12.30 

system.time(
  dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(
    Corpus(VectorSource(txt)), 
    control = list(tolower = TRUE, stopwords = stopwords("en"))
  )
)
#  User      System verstrichen 
# 157.16        0.38      158.69
```

Comment: agreed. I used `quanteda` seems faster. I am not sure whether both the `tdm` are the same! `quanteda` gives a `sparse matrix` is it the same as the one produced in `tm`?

Comment: The dfmSparse class is a sparse matrix version of dfm-class, inheriting dgCMatrix-class from the Matrix package. It is the default object type created when feature counts are the object of interest, as typical text-based feature counts tend contain many zeroes. As long as subsequent transformations of the dfm preserve cells with zero counts, the dfm should remain sparse. tm gives you an object of class TermDocumentMatrix or class DocumentTermMatrix (both inheriting from a simple triplet matrix in package slam) containing a sparse term-document matrix or document-term matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd try

```
tm_map(doc.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
```

Because `tolower()` isn't in a list of `getTransformations()`

Comment: tried the above syntax too! but no improvement in the performance

Comment: could u show how u are creating a corpus, cause I haven't faced such issue having corpus over 100mb and processing time < 2min, and yep, my RAM is 4 times bigger but i'm pretty sure it shouldn't be a case

Comment: `corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(vector_list))
  
  skipWords <- function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords("english"))
  funcs <- list(tolower, removePunctuation, removeNumbers, stripWhitespace, skipWords)
  a <- tm_map(corpus, FUN = tm_reduce, tmFuns = funcs)
  a <- tm_map(a, PlainTextDocument)`