# R tm content_transformer: custom function slow

Tags: r, tm

I am cleaning a text corpus of about 50k elements, 150MB, mostly using `tm`'s built-in functions. These are all pretty snappy - they get done in a minute at most. Then I do one custom cleaning step to replace proper names with a placeholder, like so:

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(function(x) gsub(x, pattern = myNames, replacement = "ProperName")))
```

where myNames is a long string (about 1000 names) in this type of format:

```
"\\b(name1|name2|name3|name4)\\b"
```

This takes a long time (half an hour / an hour) to run - and I don't see why it should be so much slower than, say, `removeWords`. Is there an obvious problem with the way I'm specifying this?

I know [other packages have been suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377483/remove-stopwords-and-tolower-function-slow-on-a-corpus-in-r/38378229#38378229) and I do think I've found a workaround using `stringr` (or could be `gsub` itself I suppose) to substitute the words before I even create the corpus, but it just seems silly...

Comment: Possible duplicate (at least strongly related) [regex - faster approach than `gsub`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29273928/903061) The answer there is to use `stringi::stri_replace_all_regex`, and a comment suggests that even just setting `perl = TRUE` in `gsub()` can speed things up substantially.

Comment: If the tm functions are slow, try parallelizing them. check `?tm_parLapply` on how to do this. Or if you are more comfortable with the future framework you can use the future.apply package.

Comment: Setting `perl = TRUE` transformed the performance of this function - from pushing an hour to a matter of seconds...